# How to get the namspace of a url

Tags: python, web-services, soap-client

what is the namespace of the following url.

http://slhepp0034.ctsslou.visteon.com/login/login.htm#v37632/p10454

and what is the wsdl format, if we write for in soap WSDL format

Answer (score 2):

Understand the basics **first**. What is a XML namespace? **XML namespaces** are used for providing uniquely named elements and attributes in an XML document. They are defined in a W3C recommendation. An XML instance may contain element or attribute names from more than one XML vocabulary. If each vocabulary is given a namespace, the **ambiguity** between identically named elements or attributes can be resolved.

A simple example would be to consider an XML instance that contained references to a customer and an ordered product. Both the customer element and the product element could have a child element named id. References to the id element would therefore be ambiguous; placing them in different namespaces would remove the ambiguity.

An XML namespace is declared using the reserved XML attribute xmlns or xmlns:prefix, the value of which must be a valid namespace name.

For example, the following declaration maps the "xhtml:" prefix to the XHTML namespace:

for eg. xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"

Any element or attribute whose name starts with the prefix "xhtml:" is considered to be in the XHTML namespace, if it or an ancestor has the above namespace declaration.

It is also possible to declare a default namespace. For example:xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
In this case, any element without a namespace prefix is considered to be in the XHTML namespace, if it or an ancestor has the above default namespace declaration.

Attributes are never subject to the default namespace. An attribute without an explicit namespace prefix is considered not to be in any namespace.

XML Namespaces 1.1 also introduces the option to undeclare other namespace.

Different specifications have taken different approaches on how namespace information is presented to applications.

Nearly all **programming models allow** the name of an element or attribute node to be retrieved as a **three-part name**: the local name, the namespace prefix, and the namespace URI. Applications should avoid attaching any significance to the choice of prefix, but the information is provided because it can be helpful to human readers. Names are considered equal if the namespace URI and local name match.

In addition, most models provide some way of determining which namespaces have been declared for a given element. This information is needed because some XML vocabularies allow qualified names (containing namespace prefixes) to appear in the content of elements or attributes, as well as in their names. There are three main ways this information can be provided:

```
As attribute nodes named "xmlns" or "xmlns:xxx", exactly as the namespaces are written in the source XML document. This is the model presented by DOM.
As namespace declarations: distinguished from attributes, but corresponding one-to-one with the relevant attributes in the source XML document. This is the model presented by JDOM.
As in-scope namespace bindings: in this model, the application is able to determine which namespaces are in scope for any given element, but is not able to determine which elements contain the actual declarations. This is the model used in XPath, XSLT, and XQuery.
```

**If you know these basics, I hope your question is already answered.**